# Convert curl with two headers to python

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, api-key

I'd like to convert the following OpenFIGI API command into python:

```
curl ‐v ‐X POST 'https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping'
   ‐‐header 'Content‐Type: text/json'  
   ‐‐header 'X‐OPENFIGI‐APIKEY: abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
   ‐‐data '[{"idType":"ID_WERTPAPIER","idValue":"851399"}]'
```

I managed to make it work without the X‐OPENFIGI‐APIKEY but cannot find a way to send with both headers.

Here is my working code:

```
import requests
data = [{"idType":"TICKER","idValue":"AAPL","exchCode":"US"}]
headers={"Content-Type": "text/json"}
r=requests.post('https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',headers=headers,json=data)
```

But including the API key, it returns a code '400', which according to openfigi is for 'The request body is not an array.'

```
headers={"Content-Type": "text/json",'X‐OPENFIGI‐APIKEY' :  var_key }
r=requests.post('https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',headers=headers,json=data)
```

Would anyone have an idea why it's not working? Am I missing something?
Many thanks for your help.

-- EDIT --

It seems that the issue comes from the encoding of the '-' in the key itself.

```
data = [{"idType":"TICKER","idValue":"AAPL","exchCode":"US"}]
h1= {"Content-Type": "text/json","X_OPENFIGI_APIKEY" :  "11111‐2222‐XXXX‐5555‐AAAAAAAA" }
r=requests.post('https://api.openfigi.com/v1/mapping',headers=h1,data=json.dump(data) )
r.request.headers
```

The code above shows 'X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY': '11111\xe2\x80\x902222\xe2\x80\x90XXXX\xe2\x80\x905555\xe2\x80\x90AAAAAAAA' in the request headers.

I guess it should be 'X-OPENFIGI-APIKEY': '11111-XXXX-5555-AAAAAAAA'.

Is there a way to modify my requests.post parameters to display '-' ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried converting the json manually?  Instead of `json=data` perhaps `data=json.dumps(data)`

Comment: It looks like your curl command doesn't send `"exchCode":"US"` but your requests code does.

Comment: I tried with `data = json.dumps(data)` and unfortunately it still gives me code 400. The issue seems to be related to the way I pass the api key but cannot understand why exactly...

Answer (score 0):

`\xe2\x80\x90` is a unicode hyphen, rather than ASCII. You should type the key in directly, rather than using something you cut & pasted.  Make sure you're sending ascii.

That being said, I did cut & paste your code and had no problems. (Make sure you change `json.dump(data)` to `json.dumps(data)`)

Check which version of python and requests?

Comment: It works! Writing it instead of copy pasting the key solved it.  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Carlos. The `\xe2\x80` prefix is really common. You may see it for fancy quotes, non-breaking spaces, etc. when you cut & paste from other documents.